# How to get html component value while form submitting?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

There are two pages in my ExpressJS app. home and user. I create a form in my home.js file and a navigate user.js from this form. I can get values of input components but i can not get values of other components. How can I do that ?

home.js :

```
<form action="/users" method="POST">
    <input id="input_name" type="text" placeholder="name" name="name">
    <input id="input_pwd" type="text" placeholder="password" name="pwd">
    <input id="input_mail" type="text" placeholder="mail" name="mail">

    <button type="submit" name="button_name" value='register1'>register</button>

    ....

    <div id="selection" name="selection">selection</div>
</form>
```

I populate selection div with user selections and I want to sent this data to server. I catch the request in my index.js

```
router.post('/users', function (req, res, next) {
    console.log("register name : " + req.body.name);
    console.log("register mail : " + req.body.mail);
    console.log("register pwd : " + req.body.pwd);
    console.log("register selection : " + req.body.selection);
}
```

I can get value of req.body.name, req.body.mail and req.body.pwd. but req.body.selection is always undefined. how can I get this value ?

Comment: yes. I added body-parser to my app.js. const bodyParser = require('body-parser'); app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}))

Comment: Hmm, looking into your form again, actually it's obvious that your form doesn't send `div` values, because... well it's not considered as form data. Anyway, what output do you expect for `console.log(req.body.selection)` part?

EDIT: Actually, you probably should populate that div with checkboxes or something

Comment: yes user choose some options and I populate selection div. but i can not access them. i can not find what i missed. How can I send non-input component to server side ?

Comment: One solution I can think of is to use `onSubmit` attribute in your `form` tag and create a custom form submission function. In this function, you can try to customize what you send. Or, create an `onClick` handler for your `button` to handle the form submission and use AJAX to send your data instead.

Comment: And by any chance, could you share with us your populated `div` with the options you mentioned?

Comment: i tried hardcode string only. but i can not get it also. i can not find any example in google. also i tried ajax but i can not open users page without form ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195772/discussion-between-ionizer-and-user4757345).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The html form only cares about its form elements (input, textarea and select etc) with named attributes. `div` is not an html form element. So how would you send the `div` centent through form?
There are only tricks to handle this problem.

**1- Use of `hidden` form elements**:
Put one of the form elements in the form in hidden mode which would contain data of your `div` element. As soon `div` contents changed, update the content of the hidden form element through JS. Don't forget to name this hidden form element.

**2- Submit Form through JS**:
Don't submit the form through its primitive way. (Through action attribute in the form). Use JS to submit the form.
Before submitting it, parse your `div` contents and put them in the data which is going to be submitted.

P.S: I only know these two tricks. If any other person knows more, do share.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I do not know how open users page if I do not use action attributes in form. can you give me an example ?

Comment: Its simple, if you are using ajax, once a positive response is received from server, redirect the page to users page through JS

Comment: I removed action attribute from form and I tried res.redirect('/users'); in index.js. but nothing happened.

Comment: When you are going to submit form through JS from front side, this res.redirect() won't serve your purpose. Just on front-side, when you received success after submitting the form, redirect the page to /users from front-side through JS, not from back-end side, which you are doing right now by using res.redirect()

Comment: Okay, make two routes, one for handling form, and one whatever you want to show on /users page. Make an ajax request to form handling route which on success will return true. On front-side, in ajax code, handle the success event. On encountering this success event in ajax, redirect the page to /users page. This is one of the workarounds to solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

> How can I do that ?

You can't. Submitting a form will not send the "filled out document" back to the server, it will just send back the form data, meaning the inputs names paired with their values. And `<div>`s aren't inputs.

Comment: thank you for your answer. so how can I send this data to server ? I want to send request message with selection data to server and if it is ok i want to open users page. I can use ajax to send selection data to server without using form. but this time i can not open users page ?

Comment: Use an `<input>` ?

Comment: I am using input for username, password, mail. but user choose some options for selection. becuase of that it is div.